# MIME info in mail body with PHP

Tags: php, email, mime

I've been trying to use PHP Mail function for sending an email with HTML body and an attached file. Without the attached file, I receive my HTML email without problems, but when I try to attach a file, I've got all the MIME info included in the body -also the attachment, encoded.

Here's the code for the email function without attachment - that works just fine:

```
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->headers = "From: " . Mailer::FROM_EMAIL . "\r\n";
        $this->headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $this->headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

And here's the code for the email-with-attachment version:

```
        $this->to = $to;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->attachment = 
                chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($attachment)));        

        //create a boundary string. It must be unique 
        //so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash        
        $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));                
        $this->headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com\r\n";        
        $this->headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n ";
        $this->headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$boundary\"\r\n"; 

        $this->message =    
"--PHP-mixed-$boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"

" . $message . "


--PHP-mixed-$boundary
Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"test.pdf\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

".$this->attachment ."
--PHP-mixed-$boundary--";
```

I'm using this function to send the email:

```
public function send(){

    if (preg_match(Mailer::PATTERN, trim(strip_tags($this->to)))) { 
        $cleanedTo = trim(strip_tags($this->to)); 
    } else { 
        return FALSE; 
    }                 
    return mail ($cleanedTo, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->headers); 
}
```

And I create the Mailer object as follows:

```
$mailer = new Mailer("youremail@gmail.com", "test mail", "Some <b>old good</b> HTML email", 'pdf/test.pdf');
//$mailer = new Mailer("youremail@gmail.com", "test mail", "Some <b>old good</b> HTML email");

$mailer->send();
```

And the email I receive is:

```
--PHP-mixed-e37929b72bbc6f8e3b37cf802619aac1
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"

Some <b>old good</b> HTML email


--PHP-mixed-e37929b72bbc6f8e3b37cf802619aac1
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="test.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment

JVBERi0xLjMKMSAwIG9iago8 ... FT0YK

--PHP-mixed-e37929b72bbc6f8e3b37cf802619aac1--
```

I think I'm really close to the answer, but... I'll need your help to find it.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> $this->headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n ";
> $this->headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$boundary\"\r\n";
> ```

Remove the space after the line break in the MIME-Version line. This trailing space in front of the Content-Type will make it become a continuation of the preceding line.

Btw: If Your code is running on Linux/Unix use "\n" only at the end of each line.

Comment: Thanks, Hägar!... The thing is I've changed a bit the function and right now it works just with gmail... It's driving me mad :-(

Answer (score 0):

use this header:

```
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;
```

also I suggest see this [class](http://pastebin.com/m5zAPix3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In fact, I'm using this header, as yo can see in:  "$this->headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-$boundary\"\r\n";"

Comment: I used [this](http://pastebin.com/m5zAPix3) and it worked perfect. I think there is another problem. Did you check the [class](http://pastebin.com/m5zAPix3)?

Comment: Thanks, Maysam! That class worked for me too. However, I'm still interested in knowing what is the problem with my previous code, cause I spent a lot of time trying to make it work and I hate it when that happends and I can't solve the problem. :-(